# How to run a Ruby project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

First of all I am not  Ruby developer, hence my hopefully really simple question.

I inherited a project with the following folder structure:

```
Capfile
Gemfile
Rakefile
app
config.ru
config
db
doc
lib
public 
script
spec
vendor
```

My question is:

- how to run this project in local environment? I'm running MAC OS X and have Ruby and Apache installed
- from the folder structure, are you able to identify framework/frameworks this project is utilising?

Thanks for you help!

Marcin

Comment: Try to read something about Rails: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Maybe it's a Ruby on Rails project. Try these lines in the console in the project folder:

```
gem install bundler
bundle
rake db:create && rake db:migrate
rails s
```

These commands will start Rails server at `localhost:3000`. This project requires DB to be installed. (DB type depends on `Gemfile` content). Also you should check if `config/database.yml` file is present.

Comment: Worked like magic, thank you! :) On to discovering Rails then!

Answer (score 2):

Old question, but I would open up the Gemfile and see which framework is being used. It is often the first gem in the list.